# IndentityServer4 - ValidateAsync() not hit for custom grant type

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I've implemented a custom grant type by extending IExtensionGrantValidator and added it to the DI using `.AddExtensionGrantValidator<MyAuthGrant>();`. Now, when I send a request using Postman as follows:

```
POST /identity-service/connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4430
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 29db7f3e-b23f-41f2-b5b4-bff2a17981b8
grant_type=my_authtoken=abc123client_id=rp
```

I always get the following error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Missing or Invalid token."
}
```

Interestingly enough, the constructor for my MyAuthGrant class is being hit but ValidateAsync() method is not. Any idea what I might be missing here? I did everything as mentioned here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/topics/extension_grants.html

**Update:**
I even allowed it for the client like

```
ICollection<string> grantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword
    .Concat(new [] { GrantTypeConstants.MyAuth })
    .ToArray();

new Client
{
   ...
   AllowedGrantTypes = grantTypes,
   ...
}
```

**Update2:**
Here is the implementation of MyAuthGrant in case anyone was wondering.

```
namespace Abc
{
    public class MyAuthGrant : IExtensionGrantValidator
    {
        public string GrantType => GrantTypeConstants.MyAuth;

        public MyAuthGrant(
            ...
            )
        {
            ...
        }

        public async Task ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                ...
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(user.Id.ToString(), GrantType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.UnauthorizedClient);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, did that as well.

Comment: Shouldn't it be:  grant_type=my_authtoken&scope=abc123&client_id=rp

Comment: @RuardvanElburg That probably is a Postman bug for when it converts it into code. I was expecting a "&' there as well but it works without it for the normal flow: grant_type=passwordusername=user@replenium.compassword=abc9876client_id=rp

Comment: Have you tried sample console client? I have set this up using the same link for reference and it works no problems. Setup a secret for the client and also set up only your custom grant to be allowed `AllowedGrantTypes = "myauth"`. Also tryu sending your payload as the last parameter in the web request, so `token=abc123` as last parameter.

Comment: How did you register the validator in startup: services.AddIdentityServer()? I think it should be one of the the last steps.

Comment: I have this exact same issue and I have .AddExtensionGrantValidator<DelegationGrantValidator>(); as the very last thing on AddIdentityServer().

Comment: Have you enabled AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser= true in new Client in Server?

Comment: Its surely request issue. unless we find something missing on server as your have not published whole code. Feel free to connect on chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/211547/validateasync-issue?tab=general